# opencart 2.x: How to identify which submit button was pressed?

Tags: php, opencart2.x

On my front page in opencart I've got a panel with login (which says that user is logged or if not then asks for login and password) and it has IF condition inside the controller:

```
if (($this->request->server['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') && $this->validate()) {
```

The contact page also has the same IF condition. When I press the submit button on my contact page, the front page reloads and the both controllers call validate() function after that I get error in my login panel. I'm thinking about adding to that IF condition another check of which submit button was pressed? How to manage this, so my login panel would use the same data when reloading but only when submit button from contact page is pressed?

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12850041/how-can-i-detect-which-submit-button-was-pressed)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have these buttons:

```
<input type="submit" name="button1" />
<input type="submit" name="button2" />
```

Then you can test which one was clicked as follows:

```
if (isset($_POST['button1'])) {

} else if (isset($_POST['button2'])) {

}
```